# Date.parse , gets NaN

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

I have two time inputs, and for some validation, I have a directive, where I pass the sdate through the attribute of end time input.

```
<input type="time" data-ng-model="activity.stime">

<input type="time" data-ng-model="activity.etime" data-ng-date="activity.etime" data-min-date={{activity.stime}}>
```

Directive here :

```
app.directive('ngDate', function () {
'use strict';
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, aCtrl) {              
        function myValidation(etime) {        
            var c = attr.minDate;
            console.log(c);
            var a = Date.parse(c);
            console.log(a);  

        }
           aCtrl.$parsers.push(myValidation); //validation purposes
    }    
};
```

});
I have a variable in the **directive**, which gets some time from an input's attribute .When I do a console.log

```
 var c = attr.minDate;
console.log(c)
```

I get a value of "1970-01-01T03:11:00.000Z" , which is the correct value. But, when I try to do

```
var a = Date.parse(c);
console.log(a);
```

I get a NaN. But it works if I were to put the string directly such as 
 `var a = Date.parse("1970-01-01T03:11:00.000Z");`

What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] - there is no way to know what actual value of `c` is (likely different from what you believe it is).

Comment: If `Date.parse(c)` doesn't work then it's not the value you think it is. Because using a string *literal* or a string *value* doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Do a console.log(typeof c); - if it's not a string, then that's you're problem.

Comment: @TadDonaghe it's a string

Comment: What your describing doesn't make sense, therefore something else must be going on.. We need to see it repro'd to help (Provide code that makes this happen).

Comment: The code currently provided doesn't allow us to reproduce this problem. I suggest attempting to deconstruct your code into the simplest possible example and see if you're still getting this issue. I'm going to guess you won't. Putting it back together will allow you to see what you've missed.

Comment: @DylanWatt added some codes, hopefully it can help

Comment: @TadDonaghe updated

Comment: @user3787219 : if you dont have hesitation to use third party js than i would like to suggest you to use moment js.for eg - >  moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

Comment: @user3787219 : refer doc - >http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Try using dateFormat